# special-character " ' " is not displaying properly PHP?

Tags: php, special-characters

I have already ask a question related this, according to one answer I use `<meta charset=utf-8>`, after using this, the other **special-characters** are displaying properly but " ' " is not displaying properly yet.

Comment: show us result what you are getting

Comment: Is your page saved as utf-8 ?

Comment: Define "not properly". How does it display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you use UTF-8 everywhere that PHP is configure to handle UTF-8.

In the html, add the meta-tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

And save it in UTF-8 format. here is [how to do that in notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/21135/how-can-i-edit-unicode-text-in-notepad).

[Enable UTF-8](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) in the `php.ini`:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

For a full manual check [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)